# PostgreSQL 9.4.4 Crashing

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, corruption

We are having 9.4.4 version running on linux( PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit)  which is crashing unexpectedly and coming up on its own.
What can be wrong, at time it fails while executing a query (update) at times at delete query and at times and checkpoint. Looks like OOM Killer is getting triggered by I am not sure why.

Second is that I am having some partition tables(almost 2000 + Partitioned Tables) . Can that be a problem if my query is trying to update or delete from the partitioned table.

Following is one of the sample logs.

```
2015-08-28 09:58:14.534 UTC >LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 5901) was terminated by signal 9: Killed
2015-08-28 09:58:14.582 UTC >LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.608 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.

2015-08-28 09:58:14.639 UTC >DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2015-08-28 09:58:14.639 UTC >HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2015-08-28 09:58:15.390 UTC >LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2015-08-28 09:58:19.334 UTC >LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-08-28 09:52:39 UTC
2015-08-28 09:58:19.883 UTC >LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2015-08-28 09:58:19.893 UTC >LOG:  redo starts at 6D/AE079F48
2015-08-28 09:58:32.298 UTC >LOG:  unexpected pageaddr 6D/88426000 in log segment 000000010000006D000000E7, offset 4349952
2015-08-28 09:58:32.298 UTC >LOG:  redo done at 6D/E7425DB0
2015-08-28 09:58:32.299 UTC >LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2015-08-28 09:55:04.414434+00
2015-08-28 09:58:38.717 UTC >LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2015-08-28 09:58:38.746 UTC >LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-08-28 09:58:38.746 UTC >LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: _was terminated by signal 9_: so it does not crash, it's killed from outside. OOM is a plausible candidate indeed. You need to figure out what processes eat too much RAM; start with the kernel logs at the moment of the kill.

Comment: What is the output of dmesg (which should have the OOMKiller output in it)? How much RAM is available on the machine? What items have you changed in your  `postgresql.conf`? What items have you changed in your `sysctl.conf`? Do you have swap enabled? These would definitely be helpful in diagnosing the reason for the OOMKiller firing.